# How to change the current directory of a Explorer-type custom dialog?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm currently customizing an Explorer-type custom dialog and I want to add a recent file combo box. I have already added the combo box the recent file items. I was also able to map them to their file path. But I'm  having problems on changing the working directory of the explorer type dialog. Upon selecting a file on the combo box, I want the directory to change with the corresponding folder location of the selected file. See image attached.

[Recent File Combo Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cn7f.jpg)

```
  // Get the index of the selected item in the combo box
  const int iCmbIdx = CBGetCurSel(cOPEN_RECENTFILE_CMB);
  if (iCmbIdx < 0) break; // Break if it is invalid

  
  int iDefaultFileIndex = -1;
  // Key - value pair 
  // Returns the index of the file saved in registry
  int iFileIdx = lIndex.GetValue(iCmbIdx, iDefaultFileIndex);
  if (iFileIdx < 0 ) break; // Index not found


  // Build the folder path
  tchar szItem[LSTR];
  tchar szFilePath[LSTR];
  tsprintf(szItem, TEXT("File%d"), iFileIdx);
  LUserSettingGetString(TEXT("RecentFileList"), szItem, TEXT(""), szFilePath);
  if (szFilePath[0] == 0) break;
  LFile::GetFolderFromPath(szFilePath, szFilePath);

  if (!SetCurrentDirectory(szFilePath)) {
     LFDEBUG("SetCurrentDirectory failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
     break;
  }
```

There are no errors in SetCurrentDirectory() call but the dialog will not go to the specified location. Is this the correct API to use to change the location of the folder?

This is the flags I used for the OPENFILENAME structure:

```
   ofn.Flags = OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST  | OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE | OFN_ENABLEHOOK;
```

Comment: `SetCurrentDirectory` sets the working directory for the process,i doubt that's what you want. Please show a [mre]

Comment: OPEFILENAME is legacy. You should use IFileDialog instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog and it comes with lots of programmatic features, events,etc.

Comment: I have tried to use lFileDialog but it doesn't give much control on the layout.

Comment: Once you have an IFileDialog, you can QueryInterface for IFileDialogCustomize https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifiledialogcustomize (and also for IFileDialog2, IOleWindow to get the HWND)

Comment: You can use these [Explorer-Style Control Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/open-and-save-as-dialog-boxes#explorer-style-control-identifiers) to control dialog.

Answer (score 1):

`SetCurrentDirectory` is too low level, these dialogs use the shell namespace to navigate.

The classic open/save dialog API [provides some messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/common-dialog-box-messages) to control it but changing the directory is not one of them. This leaves you with hacks like this:

```
void SetOpenSaveDlgFolderWithTextHack(HWND hTopDlg, LPCTSTR Path)
{
    HWND hCtl = GetDlgItem(hTopDlg, 0x47C); // Combo
    if (!hCtl) hCtl = GetDlgItem(hTopDlg, 0x480); // Old Edit
    if (hCtl && *Path && (int)(INT_PTR) SendMessage(hCtl, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (SIZE_T) Path) > 0)
    {
        SendMessage(hTopDlg, WM_COMMAND, IDOK, (SIZE_T) GetDlgItem(hTopDlg, IDOK));
    }
}

void SetOpenSaveDlgFolderWithShellBrowserHack(HWND hTopDlg, LPCTSTR Path)
{
    UINT cwm_getishellbrowser = WM_USER + 7;
    IShellBrowser *pSB, *pUnk = (IShellBrowser*) SendMessage(hTopDlg, cwm_getishellbrowser, 0, 0);
    if (pUnk && SUCCEEDED(pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IShellBrowser, (void**) &pSB)))
    {
        if (PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl = ILCreateFromPath(Path))
        {
            pSB->BrowseObject(pidl, SBSP_ABSOLUTE);
            ILFree(pidl);
        }
        pSB->Release();
    }
    else
    {
        SetOpenSaveDlgFolderWithTextHack(hTopDlg, Path);
    }
}
```

To find `hTopDlg`, use `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` and call `GetParent` on the HWND given to you in the hook proc for WM_NOTIFY:CDN_INITDONE.

As mentioned by  Simon Mourier in the comments, the new dialogs added in Vista allows you to call [`IFileDialog::SetFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-setfolder) to change the current folder. The downside of this API is that you don't have full control of the dialog layout and you have to implement a COM object to catch events.

Comment: Can you confirm that CWM_GETISHELLBROWSER only works inproc? Or is there a way to get some shell interface from Common Dialog (not from Explorer views) from another process?

Comment: @Simon Inproc only like most of the shell stuff. The message is basically undocumented because it was only ever documented in a KB article and Microsoft deletes most of the old articles for some crazy reason.

Comment: Well, not everything is inproc, IShellWindows works out-of-proc and is indirectly capable of proxying the whole associated shebang (IShellView, IFolderView, etc.) for explorer windows, but I can't find a way to attach somehow to an out-of-proc Common Dialog IShellView.